# What are the advantages of the Image Recall Technique over other traditional classroom learning methods?

Tags: learning-methods, image-recall-technique

I found an [article on the Omniglot website](https://www.omniglot.com/language/articles/langlearning.htm) that states that the Image Recall technique is a good method to learn a new language. It also states that software like Rosetta Stone use this technique.

> The idea is that you look at images and hear the native word for that image at the same time, thus developing a mental association between the two. If successful, when you attempt to recall the word at a later date, the image will appear in your mind and affirm the correct choice of word.

My question is that what advantage does this learning method have over other traditional classroom learning methods?

**Update from comments**: By other traditional classroom learning methods I mean the method where a person teaches a language by using stories, poems, essays (with a meaning in our native lang) and conducting speech competitions, etc...

Comment: @AlexA. By Traditional Classroom learning I mean the method where a person teaches a language by using stories, poems, essays (with a meaning in our native lang) and conducting speech competitions, etc...

Comment: @KolappanNathan Please edit the question with your additional information. Also are you limiting the scope to only vocabulary building, or learning a language in general?

Comment: Please add the additional details of your request to your question. See [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), and if deleted in the future the additional information will be lost.

Comment: The image recall technique is a method for learning vocabulary. Standard classroom learning teaches a variety of different language skills. I'm my own school time learning vocabulary was commonly assigned as homework.

Comment: The "image recall technique" has been part of the various teaching techniques used within the classroom for ages, so I do not get the point of your question.

Comment: @Laure In my school Image recall learning was not a part of classroom learning. I have also updated my question to explain what I meant by the word **traditional** classroom learning.

Comment: Just because your school does not use it doest not mean it is not a traditional classroom teaching method elsewhere.  "using stories, poems, essays" are other techniques, used for different purposes. As the link you give says Image Recall Technique is a "classic method of language learning".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You learn images faster than words. So associating images with their respective word helps people learn the word faster.

In this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/get-psyched/201207/learning-through-visuals), it states:

> A large body of research indicates that visual cues help us to better retrieve and remember information. The research outcomes on visual learning make complete sense when you consider that our brain is mainly an image processor (much of our sensory cortex is devoted to vision), not a word processor. In fact, the part of the brain used to process words is quite small in comparison to the part that processes visual images.

Basically, your brain was built to remember images a lot faster than words, which can take quite a while. For example, you might remember a restaurant's name after seeing its logo, which is taken in and stored by the brain as a visual. This type of association between images and words can help others retrieve the correct words faster. This also will help with retention and comprehension:

> Based upon research outcomes, the effective use of visuals can decrease learning time, improve comprehension, enhance retrieval, and increase retention.

This is usually why lots of people are *visual* learners: because they learn by associating images with the correct terms, and images are stored as memory faster.